# Second derivative of an inverse function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inverse

By the inverse function theorem, we know that $G'(x)=1/F'(G(x))$, where $G=F^{-1}$. I want to obtain $G''(x)$, but I don't know how to get the derivative of $F'(G(x))$. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (F'\circ G)(x) = F''(G(x))G'(x),
$$
and insert the value for $G'$ that you have obtained before.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{f'(g(x))}\right)&=-\frac{1}{\big(f'(g(x))\big)^2} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}\Big(f'(g(x))\Big)}_{\text{Chain Rule}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{\big(f'(g(x))\big)^2} \cdot f''(g(x))\underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}\Big(g(x)\Big)}_{\text{Chain Rule}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{\big(f'(g(x))\big)^2} \cdot f''(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)\\
\end{align}